# How to remove the special characters in a string

Tags: sql, regexp-substr

Here is the situation

```
WITH q AS (SELECT '( This is Z12783)' AS sentence FROM DUAL)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(sentence,'Z[0-9].*')
FROM q;
```

Desired Output:
Z12783

But the Output I get is:
Z12783)

Is there a way to remove the ')' at the end within this REGEXP_SUBSTR function?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex pattern is slightly off.  Use this version:

```sql
WITH q AS (SELECT '( This is Z12783)' AS sentence FROM DUAL)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(sentence,'Z[0-9]+')
FROM q;
```

Your current regex pattern `Z[0-9].*` actually says to match `Z`, followed by one digit, followed by the rest of the string.  You mean to use `Z[0-9]+`, which matches `Z` followed one or more digits only.

Comment: What does the '+' do?

Comment: @StackOne The `+` is a quantifier meaning one or more of whatever precedes.  In this case, then it means one or more digits.